# Using Eloquent outside Laravel - Eager/Lazy Loading Related Models

Tags: wordpress, laravel, lazy-loading, eloquent, eager-loading

I am using Laravel's Eloquent inside a wordpress plugin.

Product Model:

```
<?php namespace GD;

use Country;

class Product extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Country', 'CountryId');
    }
}
```

Country Model:

```
<?php namespace GD;

use Product;

class Country extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Product');
    }
}
```

I can query any model using standard Laravel syntax:

```
$products = $this->product->where('MetalId', '=', 1)
->where('ProductTypeId', '=', '2')
->orderBy('Name')->orderBy('CountryId')
->get();
```

However I am unable to eager/lazy load related models:

```
$products = $this->product->with('country')->where('MetalId', '=', 1)
->where('ProductTypeId', '=', '2')
->orderBy('Name')->orderBy('CountryId')
->get();
```

Error Message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Country' not found in .../vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 593
```

So I figured that this must be a namespace problem, so I updated my model code to:

```
return $this->belongsTo('\\GD\\Country', 'CountryId');

and

return $this->hasMany('\\GD\\Product');
```

However when I run the query on the Product Model and vardump the results, I get:

```
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["country"]=>
    NULL
  }
```

Comment: Have you configured a class autoloader? And how are you handling the situation if another plugin includes the Eloquent files as well - especially if it's a different version of Eloquent?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, and it was indeed a namespace issue.

Try adding only single back-slashes to the namespace strings, since you are using single quotes to enclose them.

Like so:

```
return $this->belongsTo('GD\Country', 'CountryId');

and

return $this->hasMany('GD\Product');
```

Also, please ensure that you are using the full namespace. In my app, I used 'App\Models\ModelName'.

Should it be something like 'App\Models\GD\ModelName' for your app? That depends upon your application structure.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed the namespace declaration in your model definition. So 'GD\ModelName' is correct. However, try the single back-slash suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, but the single `\\` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Try loading a single record. Are you able to read that record's country? Eg: Product::find(product_id)->country;

Comment: Hey. Were you able to do what I requested in the previous comment?